# How can I off dispatch() helper in Laravel controller method when testing?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm having a problem while testing this method of controller:

```
public function foo() {
    $data = [
        'content' => $content,
        'from' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
    $report = (new BlockedItemsReport($data))->onQueue('default');
    dispatch($report);
    return back();
```

}

This is a test method:

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $response = $this->call('POST', route('make.foo'), [
        'content' => $faker->text(200),
    ]);
    $response->assertRedirect('/');
}
```

What I should do with dispatch() helper for switch off the action?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**Your controller**

```
public function foo($check) {
    $data = [
        'content' => $content,
        'from' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
    $report = (new BlockedItemsReport($data))->onQueue('default');

    if($check){
       dispatch($report);  Подскажите, как?
    }
    return back();
}
```

**Your test method**

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $response = $this->call('POST', route('make.foo',[$check => false]), [
        'content' => $faker->text(200),
    ]);
    $response->assertRedirect('/');
}
```

I hope your peace :)